# Can I run a single .js file with node to interact with a (local) database?

Tags: mysql, node.js

Just got into node and working with remote machines (via aws) for the first time today.  I wrote a file that takes input (piped into it), and hopefully after your help will stuff some of this input in a database.

The file takes the input fine when I run "node fileName",  however when I introduce the database part, it complains of unexpected identifier: `function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { insert mysql`

The following is the beginning of my file:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'user10',
  password : 'abcdef',
  database : 'mydb'
});
connection.connect();
```

I npm installed mysql I think; in the directory of the file there is a node modules folder in which there is a folder called mysql.  Do node modules only work if I'm actually running a server or have an app.js or something like that?  This stuff is so new to me I'm not sure I fully understand what exactly node is; I know I could have written this more easily in Ruby but I wanted to try something new.

Comment: no requirement for server or anything usually, unless your database itself states such. Any `myFile.js` would be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do node modules only work if I'm actually running a server or have an
>   app.js or something like that?

You can run any kind of scripts written in JavaScript language with Node, including softwares running like web servers.

A script named `hello.js` containing the single line `console.log('Hello World!);` can be run with the command `node hello.js`.

The `require` function is used to include another JavaScript file or node module managed with `npm`.

According to the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders):

> If the module identifier passed to
>   require() is not a native module, and does not begin with '/', '../',
>   or './', then Node.js starts at the parent directory of the current
>   module, and adds /node_modules, and attempts to load the module from
>   that location. Node will not append node_modules to a path already
>   ending in node_modules.

In your case, you will need to run the `npm install` command followed by every package name you `require()` in the scripts you plan to run, this includes `mysql` for instance.

You won't need to run that command until you remove the `node_modules` folder. If you don't want to install the packages all the time, I'd suggest you to create a package by running `npm init`, then adding the `--save` flag to `npm install` each time you want to add a package permanently, the packages list will be stored inside the `package.json` file.

You'll be able to run `npm install` without any other argument to install all your `--save`d packages as long as the `package.json` file is present.

```
npm init
npm install --save mysql
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```